# Availability group restore and reseed

Tags: sql-server, availability-group

Is it possible to restore the database backup on the primary replica of availability group and then reseed it to the secodary replica without coppying backup files?

Preferably I need to get the script (not GUI) that does it.

So far I'm doing this

1. Remove database from AG
2. restore database on primary
3. Add database to AG on primary

AG is set to automatic seeding, but after adding database to AG seeding does not happend.
How is it supposed to work?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Auto reseed can take some time depending on the size, and in my experience is not particularly reliable, you are probably better restoring a backup to the secondary and applying log backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the key was to first remove DB from secondary replica, then drop db on secondary replica. Then remove DB from AG on primary replica and then option to reseed becomes available.
SQL version 2019